# android monkey runner scripts

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I was trying to run a a sample python program using monkey runner but unfortunately throwing an error of this type :

```
Can't open specified script file

Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE

-s      MonkeyServer IP Address.
-p      MonkeyServer TCP Port.
-v      MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO, WARNING, SEVERE, OFF)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 so any one can guide me how to resolve this and how to use monkey runner to execute this type of things

Comment: This android developing related question should go to stackoverflow.

Comment: and what's your command line ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that making the path to the script absolute helped monkeyrunner.
I am invoking the runner from a Python script where a helper class has a startMonkey method:

```
def startMonkey(self, monkeyScript):
    command = [ self.env + '\\tools\\monkeyrunner.bat' ]
    command.append( os.path.abspath( monkeyScript ) )
    return startProcess( command )
```

This seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Script file should be a full path file name try below `monkeyrunner c:\test_script\first.py`

So go to the folder \ sdk \ tools

[image]

and **press shift** and **right click** to open command prompt and type **monkeyrunner c:\test_script\python_file_name.py**